# How does $' in a regex works?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

**Problem**

At http://regex101.com, it is said that `'$` will return a portion of the source string that follows the match. Yet it doesn't work like this for me.

**Example**

For example, I need to replace text in JSON. I need to remove some text from JSON after certain parameters.

```
 "ReportPackage": {
        "$id": "some id",
        "$type": "stuff",
        "ConnectionString": "REPLACE_HERE",
        "FtpConfiguration": {
            "$id": "some id",
            "$type": "some type",
            "Address": "some adress",
            "Password": "REPLACE_HERE",
            "Username": "REPLACE_HERE",
            "BaseDirectory": "some path"
        },
        "PgConnectionString": "REPLACE_HERE"
    }
},
"CurrentFederation": "",
"CurrentVirtualHost": "/",
"PgConnectionString": "REPLACE_HERE",
"PeriodicContinuationActivated": true
```

I need to replace the values ​​marked as `REPLACE_HERE`. I can use four separate regexes but I want to use single one(if possible).

**My Attempt to Solve the Problem**

I use this regex `$'((("Password")|("ConnectionString")|("PgConnectionString")|("Username")))(.*),` yet it doesn't work as I imagined is would. What did I do wrong?

Comment: why not just parse the json using an existing parser? Far easier than freaking around with regex.

Comment: You misunderstood the [.NET regex reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions). In fact, it should be used in the replacement pattern, see "*`$'` Includes all the text of the input string after the match in the replacement string*"

Comment: Does that mean that i should create class, then deserealize in class that i created, then change necessary values, then deserialize it. Is it far easier?

Comment: You cannot manipulate a JSON string with regex *safely*, or *without assumptions*. With assumptions, you could try `Regex.Replace(text, @"(?m)^(\s*""(?:Password|ConnectionString|PgConnectionString|Username)""\s*:\s*"")[^""]+", "$1")`.

Comment: No, it is not a matter of being easier or harder. It is a matter of being sure the replacements are done always reliable. And if `"$type": "some text that that matches your regex", ` you will have a problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked thanks.
@Cleptus i`ll discuss this with my teamlead, thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the [.NET regex reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions). In fact, `$'` is a valid *substituion* pattern, and it cannot be used to do what you want in the regex pattern.

> `$'`   Includes all the text of the input string after the match in the replacement string.

In your `$'((("Password")|("ConnectionString")|("PgConnectionString")|("Username")))(.*),` pattern, `$` simply requires the end of string position and since there are more patterns after `$`, the regex will never match any string.

More, JSON strings cannot be safely manipulated with regex *without assumptions*.

*If* your values do not contain double quotes, and *if* the JSON string is indented the way you showed you could try

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?m)^(\s*""(?:Password|ConnectionString|PgConnectionString|Username)""\s*:\s*"")[^""]+", "$1")
```

where

- `(?m)` - makes `^` match start of line positions
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\s*""(?:Password|ConnectionString|PgConnectionString|Username)""\s*:\s*"")` - Group 1 that captures

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `"` - a `"` char
  - `(?:Password|ConnectionString|PgConnectionString|Username)` - one of the strings listed
  - `"\s*:\s*"` - `"`, a `:` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces and then a `"`
- `[^"]+` - one or more chars other than `"`.

The `$1` replacement pattern replaces the matches with Group 1 value.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28%5Cs*%22%28%3F%3APassword%7CConnectionString%7CPgConnectionString%7CUsername%29%22%5Cs*%3A%5Cs*%22%29%5B%5E%22%5D%2B&i=%20%22ReportPackage%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%24id%22%3A%20%22some%20id%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%24type%22%3A%20%22stuff%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ConnectionString%22%3A%20%22REPLACE_HERE%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22FtpConfiguration%22%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%24id%22%3A%20%22some%20id%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%24type%22%3A%20%22some%20type%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Address%22%3A%20%22some%20adress%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Password%22%3A%20%22REPLACE_HERE%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Username%22%3A%20%22REPLACE_HERE%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22BaseDirectory%22%3A%20%22some%20path%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22PgConnectionString%22%3A%20%22REPLACE_HERE%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%22CurrentFederation%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%22CurrentVirtualHost%22%3A%20%22%2F%22%2C%0D%0A%22PgConnectionString%22%3A%20%22REPLACE_HERE%22%2C%0D%0A%22PeriodicContinuationActivated%22%3A%20true&r=%241).

To do that properly, parse JSON string and clear out the key values you need. See [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)